# using sql MONTH or YEAR in cakephp find queries

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3

I'm trying to get all the users that has registered during a particular month using a query like this in a cakephp application:

```
$registered_users = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'MONTH(User.date)' => 10
    )
));
```

The query above is supposed to return me all the users that has registered during the month of october for example, but for some reason, I get the following error:

```
1054: Unknown column 'User.date' in 'where clause'
```

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error please?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$condition['MONTH(date) >'] = '10';
$registered_users = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => $condition,
));
```

Comment: It worked for me, I just had to remove > after 'MONTH(date)'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I dont have enough points to add this as a comment.

Make sure in your database `User.date` column actually exists. Maybe you wanted to use `User.created`?